# How to generate bitmap one after another from y axis in android game

Tags: android, multithreading, android-bitmap

I am working on a small simple game in which the hurdles coming out from top and there is an static ball which can only move on x-axis.When the hurdles coming out from top the user have to move the ball to avoid the collision.

I am placing 3 moving hurdles at a time.but my problem is they are coming out together i.e all three hurdles have the same y-axis values.I want it to come out one by one with some specific distance.

How can i achieve this.
Here is my GamePanel Class:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread = null;
    private Ball ball;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Paint paint;
    private Canvas canvas;

    volatile boolean playing = true;

    private int hurdleCount = 3;
    private Hurdles[] hurdles;

    private int screenX, screenY;
    private Rect ball_detectCollision;

    public GamePanel(Context context, final int screenX, final int screenY) {
        super(context);

        ball = new Ball(context, screenX, screenY);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();

        this.screenX = screenX;
        this.screenY = screenY;

        paint = new Paint();
        canvas = new Canvas();

        hurdles = new Hurdles[hurdleCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < hurdleCount; i++) {
            hurdles[i] = new Hurdles(context, screenX, screenY);
        }

        ball_detectCollision = new Rect(ball.getBall_x(), ball.getBall_y(), ball.getBitmap().getWidth(), ball.getBitmap().getHeight());
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                System.out.println("Surface Created");

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

                System.out.println("Surface Changed");
                thread = new Thread(GamePanel.this);
                thread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                System.out.println("Surface Destroyed");
            }
        });
    }


    private void draw() {

        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), updatedValue, ball.getBall_y(), paint);
        ball.setBall_x(updatedValue);

        ball_detectCollision.left = ball.getBall_x();
        ball_detectCollision.top = screenY - ball.getBitmap().getHeight() - 260;
        ball_detectCollision.right = ball.getBall_x() + ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        ball_detectCollision.bottom = screenY - ball.getBitmap().getHeight() - 260 + ball.getBitmap().getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < hurdleCount; i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(hurdles[i].getBitmap(), hurdles[i].getX(), hurdles[i].getY(), paint);
        }
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (playing) {
            update();
            draw();
            control();
        }
    }

    private void update() {

        for (int i = 0; i < hurdleCount; i++) {
            hurdles[i].update();

            if (Rect.intersects(getBall_detectCollision(), hurdles[i].getDetectCollision())) {
                System.out.println("Collision Detected");

                playing = false;
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showGameOverMessage();

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    public void pause() {

        playing = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is my Hurdle Class

```
  public class Hurdles {

        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int speed = 20;

        private int maxX;
        private int minX;

        private int maxY;
        private int minY;

        private Rect detectCollision;

        public Hurdles(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.hurdle);
            maxX = screenX - bitmap.getWidth();
            maxY = screenY;
            minX = 0;
            minY = 0;
            Random generator = new Random();
            detectCollision = new Rect(x, y, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            x = generator.nextInt(maxX);
            y = minY;
        }

        public void update() {
            y += speed;

            if (y > maxY - getBitmap().getHeight()) {
                Random generator = new Random();
                y = minY;
                x = generator.nextInt(maxX);
            }

            detectCollision.left = x;
            detectCollision.right = x + bitmap.getWidth();
            detectCollision.top = y;
            detectCollision.bottom = y + bitmap.getHeight();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add delay/gap between hurdles, you can do it in your GamePanel constructor like :

```
public GamePanel(Context context, final int screenX, final int screenY) {
    super(context);

    int gapBetweenHurdles = 100;
    int gap = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hurdleCount; i++) {
        //(screenY - gap) will move your hurdle above the screen
        hurdles[i] = new Hurdles(context, screenX, screenY - gap);
        //increment the gap
        gap += gapBetweenHurdles;
    }
......
}
```

So the gap between the hurdles is 100 pixels as i have written randomly. If you want specific gap, you can set `gapBetweenHurdles` to some percentage of the screen height.

**EDIT:**
You have to pass the initial `X` and `Y` position to the hurdle constructor and then in update method of the hurdle class increment the `Y` value and in Hurdle class, `getY()` should return `Y`.

Comment: Its working but hurdle disappears when it crosses the ball object

Comment: No. its little bit above from the bottom of the screen

Comment: What should happen when hurdle crosses ball?

Comment: It should go to the end of screen and then pass away the screen

Comment: The Hurdles.class you have posted, is it the entire class?There maybe some condition you have written in it so maybe disappearing

Comment: there are some getter and setters which i didn't posted..nothing else..that's all of the hurdle class

Comment: Change your `if (y > maxY - getBitmap().getHeight()) ` in `update()` method to `if (y > screenHeight) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132783/discussion-between-abhaybohra-and-akshay-bhat-ab).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showGameOverMessage();

                    }
                },timeOffsetInMillis);
```

If the gaps can be the same you can set `timeOffsetInMillis = i * gapInMillis`